# Understanding class referencing over program lifecycle

Tags: java

What I am trying to understand is class referencing and how that reference changes over the life cycle of a program running.  For example

```
ClassRef ref = new ClassRef();
ref.setVariableOne(1);
ref.setVariableTwo(2);
```

So I know that this will create an object named `ref` which I can pass around in my code to where I need it, I can use serialization to save and load it which is fine.  If I were to create some kind of output it would show that `ref = 1,2`

But what about if I were to do this

```
ArrayList<ClassRef> refArray = new ArrayList<ClassRef>
refArray.add(ref);
ref.setVariableOne(3);
```

I have added my object to the array and then changed one of the variables, does the object in the array also update, or does it "save" that as a snap shot at the  time it was added, so if I were to output from the array it would give `ref = 1,2` or would it show that `ref = 3,2`

Comment: What is this `ClassRef` class that you speak of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have added my object to the array and then changed one of the variables, does the object in the array also update, or does it "save" that as a snap shot at the time it was added, so if I were to output from the array it would give ref = 1,2 or would it show that ref = 3,2

The object in the array list will also change and thus, it outputs `ref=3,2`.

To understand this behaviour you need to understand what are objects and references. An object is things that you can create using `new`. Here, you created a new object:

```
new ClassRef();
```

Note that the process of creating an object does not include the `ClassRef ref =` part because that part creates a reference to the object. That part says "`ref` will now refer to the newly created `ClassRef` object".

When you add `ref` to the array list, you are adding the reference to the array list. So now the sole element in the array list refers to the object you created in the first, the same object `ref` refers to. Note that no new objects are created.

When you mutate `ref`:

```
ref.setVariableOne(3);
```

It mutates the object that `ref` refers to, which just so happens to be the same object that the sole element in the array list is referring to. If you now do `refArray.get(0)`, it is equivalent to just doing `ref`.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am still wrapping my head around classes and objects so this makes alot of sense.

Comment: @Fluke I think my answer answers your question please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

You're are having this confusion, because you are considering `ref` as an **object**, while `ref` is a **reference to an Object**. More of it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Thus, when you pass `ref` to a method, you are not passing the **object**, but the ***reference to that Object***. Thus, the `ArrayList` contains a **reference to the Object**. Now, even if you make changes to the Object, **the reference remains the same**.

So, when you do `ref.setVariableOne(3)`, you **don't** change the reference. As the reference is what we passed, the changes affect even the `ArrayList`.

Thus, the output would be `ref=3,2`.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be `ref=3,2`

What you need to understand is that when you are adding the `ref` to the `refArray` i.e., you are just **keeping the reference to the object (pointed by `ref`) inside the `refArray` list**.

So any changes to the original object will also be noticed when you retrieve the object from the `refArray`.